# Combine values from multiple objects into one Spark Dataset

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dataset

I have a spark dataset that has 2 columns

```
  "user_id": 1,
  "order_dataset": [ 
    {
      "order_id": 2
    },
    {
      "order_id": 3
    }
 ]
```

I have another spark dataset of columns as

```
order_item_dataset - [{
 "order_id": 2,
 "item_dlm": [
   {
     "item_id": 23,
     "item_name": "airpods1",
     "item_price": 600.00000000000000000
   },
   {
     "item_id": 23,
     "item_name": "airpods2",
     "item_price": 300.00000000000000000
   }
 ]
}, {
 "order_id": 3,
 "item_dlm": [
   {
     "item_id": 23,
     "item_name": "airpods1",
     "item_price": 600.00000000000000000
   },
   {
     "item_id": 23,
     "item_name": "airpods2",
     "item_price": 300.00000000000000000
   }
 ]
}]
```

I want to match the order_id in order_dataset and order_item_data_set for each user_id
and expecting the final value

```
user_order_item_combined :
[{
  "user_id" : 1,
  "order_data_per_user" :[{
  "order_id": 2,
  "item_dlm": [
    {
      "item_id": 23,
      "item_name": "airpods1",
      "item_price": 600.00000000000000000
    },
    {
      "item_id": 23,
      "item_name": "airpods2",
      "item_price": 300.00000000000000000
    }
  ]
}, {
  "order_id": 3,
  "item_dlm": [
    {
      "item_id": 23,
      "item_name": "airpods1",
      "item_price": 600.00000000000000000
    },
    {
      "item_id": 23,
      "item_name": "airpods2",
      "item_price": 300.00000000000000000
    }
  ]
}]
}]
```

I have to combine values based on some key or say I want to join the 2 tables together
How can I combine two or more objects?

I tried to explode the order_dataset to match the order_id of order_item_dataset
but that didn't work.
is there any other generalized solution.